# How automatically switch shipment provider in the cart depending on some rules

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I looking for on possibility to automatically switch shipment providers in the cart depending on some rules.

For example, if a customer cart is < 500 EUR Shopware should automatically switch shipment providers on Express
In another case (> 500 EUR) Shopware should use DHL.

I try to use Availability rules for a shipmne provider but it doesn’t work.

Comment: how do the rules look like exactly?

Comment: @MichaelT I have 2 shipping methods. For each method, I've created two rules.
The first rule applies when an item in the cart has the tag "f". 
The second rule applies when an item in the cart has NOT the tag "f".

So one shipping method has the first rule another the second. When I add an item to the cart I've received a message "The Express shipping is unavailable"

Answer (score 1):

> I try to use Availability rules for a shipmne provider but it doesn’t work.

Yes, it does. Tested with the the current stable release `6.5.2.1`. Make sure all the shipping methods that could become available are also assigned to the sales channel. Check that in any case only one shipping method can be valid at a time. Automatic switching to another available shipping method, if the current shipping method is unavailable, was introduced with version [`6.4.8.0`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/0bc4296f58d8937271e606b31641a7f7f9db6b99/changelog/release-6-4-8-0/2021-12-02-automatically-unblocking-cart-for-storefront.md?plain=1#L1).

Comment: I've checked it all twice and it doesn’t work.

Let's check my real example:
I have 2 shipping methods. For each method, I've created two rules.
The first rule applies when an item in the cart has the tag "f". 
The second rule applies when an item in the cart has NOT the tag "f".

So one shipping method has the first rule another the second. When I add an item to the cart I've received a message "The Express shipping is unavailable". Looks like Shopware always uses the default shipping method.

Maybe it is important: I use headless Shopware.